# Swimlane ngx-charts in Angular2 - Different styles on a single line chart

Tags: javascript, angular, charts, ngx-charts

I have a single line chart, with dates on the X axis. After a certain date,
I would like the line to be a different color. Is this possible using ngx-charts?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us assume the date after which you want to change the color as T.

Now you can divide the series into 2 parts

1. The from start date to `T`
2. From `T` to end date.

And now you can plot the graph using different color for different series

The following data will generate the desired graph.

```js
var data = [
  {
    "name": "Current",
    "series": [
      {
        "value": 5599,
        "name": "2016-09-20T01:04:28.176Z"
      },
      {
        "value": 6247,
        "name": "2016-09-20T12:51:24.713Z"
      },
      {
        "value": 4283,
        "name": "2016-09-18T15:42:04.800Z"
      },
      {
        "value": 2643,
        "name": "2016-09-13T20:10:53.904Z"
      },
      {
        "value": 4105,
        "name": "2016-09-18T06:15:10.845Z"
      },
      {
        "name": "2016-09-18T13:08:42.085Z",
        "value": 4401
      },
      {
        "name": "2016-09-20T01:04:28.176Z",
        "value": 3443
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Future",
    "series": [
      {
        "value": 3443,
        "name": "2016-09-20T01:04:28.176Z"
      },
      {
        "value": 2604,
        "name": "2016-09-20T12:51:24.713Z"
      },
      {
        "value": 2158,
        "name": "2016-09-18T15:42:04.800Z"
      },
      {
        "value": 5519,
        "name": "2016-09-13T20:10:53.904Z"
      },
      {
        "value": 4532,
        "name": "2016-09-18T06:15:10.845Z"
      },
      {
        "name": "2016-09-18T13:08:42.085Z",
        "value": 2474
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: How to Implement this concept in [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org) @Hemant Kumar

Comment: This will have issue with sorting though.. So as mentioned by you it can work only for range and intermediate and two series should be mutually exclusive